# Drawing an oblique ellipse with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I discovered the tikz package just few hours ago. 
I would like to draw an oblique ellipse.. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-3,2) -- (3,2);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-3.5, 2) -- (-3,2);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (3, 2) -- (3.5,2);
\draw[gray, thick] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-3.5, 0) -- (-3,0);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (3, 0) -- (3.5,0);
\filldraw[black] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor=north] {$(p, 0)$};
\filldraw[black] (-2,2) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor=south] {$(q, 0)$};
\filldraw[black] (2,2) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor=south] {$(q, t)$};
\draw[gray, thick] (-2,1) ellipse (0.5 and 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I need to join the points (p, 0) with the point (q, t) with an ellipse.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With TikZ, the axes of ellipses are always horizontal and vertical. To rotate an ellipse, you may use a `scope` to change your coordinate system and the `calc` library to compute your new `x` and `y` vectors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-3,2) -- (3,2);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-3.5, 2) -- (-3,2);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (3, 2) -- (3.5,2);
\draw[gray, thick] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-3.5, 0) -- (-3,0);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (3, 0) -- (3.5,0);
\filldraw[black] (-2,0) coordinate (p0) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor=north] {$(p, 0)$};
\filldraw[black] (-2,2) coordinate (q0) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor=south] {$(q, 0)$};
\filldraw[black] (2,2) coordinate (qt) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor=south] {$(q, t)$};
\draw[gray, thick] (-2,1) ellipse (0.5 and 1);
\begin{scope}[shift={(p0))},x={(qt)},y={($(p0)!1!90:(qt)$)}]
  \draw[red] (.5,0) ellipse (.5 and .25);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution using `calc` library and ellipses drawn as `nodes`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style={minimum size=3pt, inner sep=0pt, fill, draw, circle}]

\draw[gray, thick] (-3,2) -- (3,2);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-3.5, 2) -- (-3,2);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (3, 2) -- (3.5,2);
\draw[gray, thick] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-3.5, 0) -- (-3,0);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (3, 0) -- (3.5,0);
\node[dot, label={below:$(p,0)$}] (p0) at (-2,0) {}; 
\node[dot, label={$(q,0)$}] (q0) at (-2,2) {}; 
\node[dot, label={$(q,t)$}] (qt) at (2,2) {}; 

\path (p0.center) let \p1=($(q0.center)-(p0.center)$) in node[ellipse, minimum height={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, minimum width=1cm, anchor=south, thick, gray, draw] {};


\path (p0.center) let \p1=($(qt.center)-(p0.center)$) in node[ellipse, minimum height={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, minimum width=1cm, anchor=south, thick, draw, gray, rotate={-atan2(\x1,\y1)}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ignasy, I'm surprise that line `\node[dot, label={$(q,0)$}] (q0) at (-2,2) {}; ` in your code works! It's new to me, that one can left out position of label and label is than correctly positioned above node!

Comment: @Zarko: By default `label` is positioned `above` the lode it labels, but you can change it with an angle or anchor: `label=30:...`. Take a look at page 239.

Comment: I learned what I escape in my the previous manual reading. Thank you for the point!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using an elegant `transform` in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

[image]

To define the transformation, you can give implicit equations for three 
non-collinear points.   The `point x of y` notation allows you to pick out the points of a path; in the case of a `fullcircle`, and hence path `e` in this example, there are 8 points equally spaced anti-clockwise starting at "3 o'clock".  So point 2 is at the top, and point 6 at the bottom.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
beginfig(1);

path e, e', hi_bar, lo_bar;  

e = fullcircle xscaled 1cm yscaled 2cm;
hi_bar = (left -- 5 right) scaled 1cm shifted point 2 of e;
lo_bar = (left -- 5 right) scaled 1cm shifted point 6 of e;

transform s; 
point 6 of e transformed s = point 6 of e;
point 2 of e transformed s = point 2 of e shifted (3.8cm,0);
point 0 of e transformed s = point 6 of e shifted (2.4cm,0);
e' = e transformed s;

drawoptions(withcolor .5 white);
draw e; r = 1/16;                            
draw subpath (0,  r) of lo_bar dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
draw subpath (r,1-r) of lo_bar;
draw subpath (1-r,1) of lo_bar dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
draw subpath (0,  r) of hi_bar dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
draw subpath (r,1-r) of hi_bar;
draw subpath (1-r,1) of hi_bar dashed withdots scaled 1/2;

drawoptions(withcolor red);
draw e';

drawoptions();

dotlabel.top (btex $(q,0)$ etex, point 2 of e);
dotlabel.urt (btex $(q,t)$ etex, point 2 of e');
dotlabel.llft(btex $(p,0)$ etex, point 6 of e);

endfig;
end
```